# Python Telebot Отслеживание реплая сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Можно ли как-нибудь отслеживать был ли ответ(реплай) на сообщение от определенного пользователя в группе в телеграм? Как отслеживать действия определённого пользователя я сделал, но вот дальше пока идей никаких нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе message есть атрибут reply_to_message что содержит объект message реплайнутого сообщения. Коротко говоря мы можем обратится:

```
if message.reply_to_message: # Если полученное сообщение является реплаем
    if message.from_user.id == who_id: # И сообщение от определённого пользователя
        # Do something
```

Можем также добавить:

```
if message.reply_to_message.id == some_mess_id
```

Если нам нужен реплай на определённое сообщение

Comment: global ids

if message.reply_to_message.id is message.from_user.id in ids6:  # Если полученное сообщение является реплаем на сообщение определенного пользователя
    if message.from_user.id in ids:  # И сообщение от определённого пользователя
        os.system("start " + file_path2) # Делаем вот это

Подскажешь что тут не так? А то не совсем понимаю как это организовать правильно...

Comment: if message.reply_to_message.id is message.from_user.id in ids6 ?

Возможно вы имели ввиду

if message.from_user.id in ids6

Comment: Я пробую сделать так:
`def func(message):
    global ids
    global ids6
    if message.reply_to_message.id == message.from_user.id in ids:
        if message.from_user.id in ids6:
            os.system("start " + file_path2)  # Делаем`

Я хочу что бы если пользователь из ids6 делал реплай на сообщение пользователя из ids то происходило действие
Но я чёт походу сам путаюсь либо не понимаю как именно это правильно указать

Comment: ' if message.reply_to_message.from_user.id in ids:
        if message.from_user.id in ids6:
            os.system("start " + file_path2)'  

Получилось)

Comment: можно ещё вопрос задать?

Comment: Да конечно можно

Comment: Есть кусок кода который выше и работает как уведомление на реплай сообщения, при помощи чего можно прикрутить таймер и сделать немного обратный функционал, например что если на сообщение от определенного пользователя не было ответа более 10 минут допустим, то срабатывает os.system("start " + file_path2)

Comment: Я не увидел тут вопроса

Comment: Как можно сделать таймер ожидания ответа на сообщение от определенного пользователя?

Comment: Можно запустить процесс который сделает запрос get_message через 10 минут и проверит был ли ответ

Comment: А где про это можно подробнее почитать?

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-timer-modulja-threading/

Comment: Благодарю! Надеюсь получится это всё собрать)